# Xunit tests got much slower, altough those tests didn't get changed

Tags: c#, xunit

I changed some tests and deleted a lot, but everything got much slower. I mean.. MUCH slower. The old main branch did 1200 tests in under 3 seconds and the new one takes about 30 minutes for 750 tests. What I really don't understand is, that the *old* tests got much slower. My new tests in this major rework are just as fast as the tests were in the old main branch, but the tests from the old main branch take up to 1-2 minutes per test!

this is one of the tests that were unchanged

```cs
        [Fact]
        public async Task ShouldAddDivisionAsync()
        {
            // Arrange
            Division someDivision = GetRandomDivision();
            Division inputDivision = someDivision;
            Division storageDivision = inputDivision;
            Division expectedDivision = storageDivision.DeepClone();

            this.apiBrokerMock.Setup(broker =>
                broker.PostDivisionAsync(inputDivision))
                .ReturnsAsync(storageDivision);

            // Act
            Division actualDivision =
                await this.divisionService.AddAsync(inputDivision);

            // Assert
            actualDivision.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedDivision);

            this.apiBrokerMock.Verify(broker =>
                broker.PostDivisionAsync(inputDivision),
                Times.Once);

            this.apiBrokerMock.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
            this.loggingBrokerMock.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
        }
```

and this is the old division class

```cs
    public class Division
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Guid DivisionManagerId { get; set; }
        public DivisionManager DivisionManager { get; set; }
        public List<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    }
```

furthermore this is the new division class

```cs
    public class Division
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string DivisionManagerId { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    }
```

So I would expect it to run just as fast as before!
A bit more information: Although running more tests, slows down the slow tests even more, the slow tests will still take up to 30 seconds per test, when run alone or in groups of 3-4.

Removing the deepclone method and the tynamix filler method (in GetRandomDivision) did make the tests a bit faster, but not enough to say it was a viable change. Also I need those tests to be random, so I cannot exchange those values for hard coded values.
I updated Xunit, but that didnt change anything. Neither for the old main branch, nor the new one.
Cleaning and rebuilding didn't do anything either. Restarting the application didnt help either.
Importing my old branch settings didnt do anything either. I'm really just trying random things at this point.

Comment: did you updated any dependency with the code change? Difference what I see is that you at least now reference to newtonsoft. But I am pretty sure this will not cause this issue.

Comment: No, I didn't. The issue was in a wholly different class it seems. Or at least that was the only point where i could fix it. It was probably just as i guessed the treestructure and that it was too deep. That made the deepcopy and should be equivalent very slow. If anyone has any suggestions, about making "should.beqeuivalent" not go down the whole path, I would appreciate any suggestions :)